How to extend an ordinary vector bundle to a $\langle k \rangle$-vector bundle?
I have this question while I am studying Steimle's paper "An additivity theorem for cobordism categories".
In this paper, a $\langle k \rangle$-vector bundle is defined to be a $P(\underline{k})$-shaped diagram in the category of vector bundles and fiberwise linear maps, where $P(\underline{k})$ denotes the power set of $\underline{k}:=\{1,...,k\}$. Such a $\langle k \rangle$-bundle $\theta$ is said to be collared if for every $A \subset B \subset \underline{k}$, there is a bundle map
$ c_{AB} : \epsilon^{B-A} \oplus \theta(A) \rightarrow \theta(B) $ which extends the structure map and satifies the obvious compatibility condition.
Then on Example 4.7(ii), the author says that given an ordinary vector bundle $\theta$, there is a canonical way of extending it to a collared $\langle k \rangle$-bundle with $\theta(\underline{k}) = \theta$. According to him, $\theta(A)$ is characterized up to unique isomorphism by having bijections
$$\operatorname{map}(\eta, \theta(A)) \cong \operatorname{map}(\eta \oplus \epsilon^{\underline{k}-A}, \theta  )                  $$
between sets of bundle maps for all (ordinary) vector bundles $\eta$.
I don't understand how the explicit construction can be made from here. Consider the simplest case, where we just extend a vector bundle $\theta$ to a collared $\langle 1 \rangle$-bundle. This means that, we need to construct a vector bundle $\theta'$, together with a bundle map $\theta' \oplus \epsilon \rightarrow \theta$ such that there are bijections
$$
    \operatorname{map}(\eta, \theta') \cong  \operatorname{map}(\eta \oplus \epsilon, \theta)
$$
which is natural in $\eta$.
I couldn't figure out how to explicitly construct such $\theta'$. I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone can give me some advice on this. Thank you!
